# Need help finding out why a file (test_find.pyc) opens at startup

Tags: macos, startup, python, library

Like the title said, IDLE opens and runs  `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ctypes/test/test_find.pyc` every time I start my computer, but I can't figure out why. It's not normal behavior for other Macs, but that's the directory macOs uses for its internal python frameworks so I don't want to delete it.

The output it displays is usually garbage, i.e.:

```
Ñò
ﾟWFXc
```

And it takes almost a minute to run!

This behavior has persisted across multiple OS upgrades.

I'd like to try to track down what the heck is calling that file.

Answer (score 2):

You could look in these locations if there is an alias to that. If not I would just delete the file.

```
/Library/StartupItems/
/Library/LaunchDaemons/
/Library/LaunchAgents/
~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

For LaunchAgents there could be a plist file related.

Comment: You should not delete things in /System as they have been installed by Apple

Comment: Helpful answer, but unfortunately nothing in those folders referenced test-find.pyc. I think I'm just going to recursively grep my entire hard drive and let it run over night :/

Comment: The file test_find.pyc belongs to the python test_find.py. As far as I know python is still in version 2.6 along many updates. What happens when you run:
`python /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ctypes/test/test_find.py` ? Running the `pyc` file should give a runtime error but not garbage. Just an idea but you could update to python 3, but I guess you really are not interested in other than to get rid of the startup issue.

Comment: @Asle I've actually got python 3 installed along with IPython and some other stuff. I use it for physics homework. As for the command, it didn't work. `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/ctypes/test/test_find.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. same thing with the pyc

Comment: @Asle though the fact that the error message mentions python 2.7 is weird right? Like something is symlinked to the wrong thing?

Comment: What does this output?
`python -V`
`python3 -V`
`whereis python`
`whereis python3`

Comment: You have to run the file like above but with `python file_path`Did you do it? I see you did not include the ´python `command first?

Comment: `python -v`should give you python 2.x and `python3 -v`should give you python 3.x. You could of course link /usr/bin/python to your python3. But I am not sure if that solve your original problem which was why this file is launching at startup.